# How to +1 to date values in a column based on conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I'm a beginner in R.

Currently, I'm cleaning a dataset that revolves around flight data and realized an issue where arrival date/times for certain rows are earlier than departure times. I want to add +1 days to ArrDate(s) that are earlier than the DepDate(s). Below is the sample of my DataFrame with the DepDate and ArrDate columns.

```
DepDate               ArrDate
<S3: POSIXct>         <S3: POSIXct>
2006-01-11 22:56:00   2006-01-11 06:55:01
2006-01-11 23:47:00   2006-01-11 06:57:01
```

I have attempted using this code but it does not seem to apply to the actual DataFrame.

```
df$ArrDate[df$ArrDate < df$DepDate] <- df$ArrDate[df$ArrDate < df$DepDate] + 1
```

Can anyone assist with this? Thank you!

Comment: You have POSIXct variables. Internally, these are seconds since the origin. Your code is adding one second. You could add 24*60*60 seconds if you don't mind potentially being off by one second (because sometimes days are not exactly 24*60*60 seconds). Alternatively, you could work with POSIXlt variables.

Comment: @Roland hey Roland, thank you so much, it worked! Thanks for sharing this fact on POSIXct variables. Will do more readings on this. Also, is it possible to focus on the date portion ie. 2006-01-11 to add 1 day to it?

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you, Wei Lun Tan?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

function_addOneDay = function(x) {
  
  x <- as.POSIXct(x,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
  x <- x + days(1)
  
}


df <- fread(
"DepDate|ArrDate
2006-01-11 22:56:00|2006-01-11 06:55:01
2006-01-11 23:47:00|2006-01-11 06:57:01"
)

df <- df[,lapply(.SD, function_addOneDay)]

df
#               DepDate             ArrDate
# 1 2006-01-12 22:56:00 2006-01-12 06:55:01
# 2 2006-01-12 23:47:00 2006-01-12 06:57:01
```

Comment: with `data.table` syntax : `df[,lapply(.SD, function_addOneDay)]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is more elegant. I replaced the code by `data.table` syntax.

Comment: @liiiiiin interesting! Thanks for your input. Will give functions a shot as I get more comfortable with the language :))

Comment: The questions says *"based on conditions"*, but this answer will change all values unconditionally. (This should be as easy as adding `DepDate > ArrDate` in the `i=` portion of the `data.table`-syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

You said "based on conditions", so I'll add a row where the conditions *do not* hold. Here's a solution, using `as.POSIXlt` as suggested in the comments:

```r
library(data.table)
DT
#                DepDate             ArrDate
#                 <POSc>              <POSc>
# 1: 2006-01-11 22:56:00 2006-01-11 06:55:01
# 2: 2006-01-11 23:47:00 2006-01-11 06:57:01
# 3: 2006-01-11 02:56:00 2006-01-11 06:55:01

DT[DepDate > ArrDate,
   ArrDate := as.POSIXct(with(list(r = as.POSIXlt(ArrDate)), { r$mday = r$mday+1; r; })) ]
DT
#                DepDate             ArrDate
#                 <POSc>              <POSc>
# 1: 2006-01-11 22:56:00 2006-01-12 06:55:01
# 2: 2006-01-11 23:47:00 2006-01-12 06:57:01
# 3: 2006-01-11 02:56:00 2006-01-11 06:55:01
```

---

Data

```r
DT <- setDT(structure(list(DepDate = structure(c(1137038160, 1137041220, 1136966160), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ArrDate = structure(c(1136980501, 1136980621, 1136980501), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```